# Trigger a javascript from ie by vba

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to extract a report from a website and export it to excel.

I am able to login and click on the first of the two div I need to click, but when I order vba to click on the second div, nothing happens.

I'm new to the business and I don't know anything about javascript, so please correct me if I'm wrong with something I say.

This is the site in question:

http://gaps.myeasy.com.br/gaps2010/Spek/Principal.aspx

I need to click on "Gestão" and then on "Controle de Atividades".

My code so far:

```
Sub LoginGaps()

Dim IE As Object

    'START INTERNET EXPLORER
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("http://gaps.myeasy.com.br/gaps2010/Spek/Principal.aspx")
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'LOGIN TO WEBSITE
    'frmLogin.Show

    'CLICK ON "GESTÃO"
    IE.document.getElementById("uwlBar_Group_2_text_top").Click

    'CLICK ON "CONTROLE DE ATIVIDADES"
    IE.document.getElementById("uwlBar_2_Item_1").Click

End Sub
```

Unfortunately I can't pass the user data here in the forum because it's not mine so I added **'** in front of the lines that do it.

Even though I don't know javascript, I could understand which script is activated when I click on "Controle de atividades", but I need to know the value of "sReturn" to be able to call it using "execScript", and I couldn't find sReturn's value because of my inexperience.

This is the script:

```
function aftermenu(sRetorno)
{
    var aRetorno=sRetorno.split("|");
    var iModulo=aRetorno[0];
    var sId=aRetorno[1];
    var sPagina=aRetorno[2];
    var sLogin=aRetorno[3];
    var iPermissao=aRetorno[4];
    if (iPermissao=="1")
    {
        if (lstItem!=null)
        {
            lstItem.style.backgroundColor="#f9f9f9";
            lstItem.onmouseover=function(){this.style.background="#d6d3d6"};
            lstItem.onmouseout=function(){this.style.background="#f9f9f9"};
            //lstItem.setSelected(false);
        }                
        lstItem=null;
        if (sId!=""){    
        lstItem=document.getElementById(sId);
        lstItem.style.backgroundColor="#dee6f3";
        lstItem.onmouseover=function(){};
        lstItem.onmouseout=function(){};
        /*
        lstItem=iglbar_getItemById(sId).element;/*
        lstItem.setSelected(true);*/}
        frmPrincipal=document.getElementById("frmPrincipal");
        frmPrincipal.location.href=sPagina;
    }            
    else
    {
         showmessage("Acesso ao módulo/função não permitido para o usuário "+sLogin+".\nConsulte o administrador do sistema.",520,constInfo,constOk,this,false);
    }
}
```

The script separates sRetorno's value into 5 variables, and after, it open a link in "frmPrincipal" which is the huge square on the page, and this link is where I find the report. 
If you can help me find how sRetorno's value is defined, I thought of 2 possibilities.

The first would be to call the script with "execScript" and the second would be to take sPagina's value and open the link directly to extract the report if it is possible.

It's important to say that the site only works on Internet Explorer, which is making it even harder, for me, to debug the code and understand where sReturn is assigned a value.

Sorry to bother you in the middle of sunday, but I have been circling around since Thursday trying to sort this out and I just do not move.

**Thank you so much guys.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the network tab of browser using F12 then click on "CONTROLE DE ATIVIDADES" (whilst logged in), you should see all the required values in the body of the POST request associated with the click you made.

The event:

[image]

The body (may look slightly different as I am not logged in):

[image]

Side note:

You should expect to see limited functionality/methods due to web designer instruction the browser to run as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help @QHarr!

Another way I could was to add a break to the code, and when I clicked where the page triggers the function, I could inspect the sRetorno's value with the code interrupted.